# android emulator with gpu emulation enabled got strange screen

Tags: android, emulation, gpu

I am using emulator to develop android app. but when I start android emulator with gpu emulation enabled. I got strange screen, status bar is at bottom of android emulator screen. when I want to input something, the IME is at top of android emulator and its direction is reverse. click character can not work, but works if click area at bottom on android emulator.
How could I fix this issue?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

http://i48.tinypic.com/1zguio9.png

http://i46.tinypic.com/30t6ptw.png

http://i50.tinypic.com/1tx4xy.png

I still have no permission to input hyperlink. so please replace @@ to // if you wanna see pictures.

Comment: I am newbie here, I have no permission to upload screenshot, Is there any other ways to upload?

Comment: just post it on some other picture hosting site and include the link here

Comment: @myth2loki Try to create a new emulator.

Comment: I have been tried to create serveral emulators, got the same issue.

Comment: I have this exact issue. Do you run a Mac?

Comment: yes, I am running it on a Mac with hd4000 gpu. win7 has no the issue.

Comment: Anyone can help me? I updated screenshot now.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been reported in Android project:

- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39026
- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35557

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39026
This issue is from me. But google hasn't fixed it till now.

Comment: they say have put in fixes in android SDK tools version 21.1rc, try and see if it works?